# What does Graphics2D's transform method do?

Tags: java, geometry, transform, graphics2d

In class Graphics2D from Java, it has a transform method.

```
public abstract void transform(AffineTransform Tx)
```

This is the description according to the documentation:

> Composes an AffineTransform object with the Transform in this Graphics2D according to the rule last-specified-first-applied. If the current Transform is Cx, the result of composition with Tx is a new Transform Cx'. Cx' becomes the current Transform for this Graphics2D. Transforming a point p by the updated Transform Cx' is equivalent to first transforming p by Tx and then transforming the result by the original Transform Cx. In other words, Cx'(p) = Cx(Tx(p)). A copy of the Tx is made, if necessary, so further modifications to Tx do not affect rendering.

I have read it several times but I still don't understand what it does. I have also tried looking for other sources, but there isn't much on g2d's transform method.

**So my question is**: What does transform exactly do? When do we use it?

It will be great if someone could explain it in a simplified manner.

Comment: Go to http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/ and download the "JDK Demos and Samples".  Once you've unpacked it, run the .jar file in the `demo/jfc/Java2D` directory.  It has an extensive demonstration of transforms (among other things), with full source code.

Comment: @VGR Thanks, I will take a look at it. But it will still be great if someone could answer my question. It will also benefit all future users.

Comment: The translate, scale, shear and rotate operations are all convenience methods that alter the transform.

Comment: @VGR, So what does transform itself do?

Comment: All of those operations, in any combination, and probably more.  My matrix math skills are a bit rusty, but the [documentation for AffineTransform](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html) seems to cover it pretty well.

Comment: @VGR I have seen and read through that link before. I am suspecting transform itself allows g2d to transform objects to  be drawn based on the given affineTransform object, yet obtaining its original affineTransform. So instead of letting us use setTransform, we use transform to "change" the affineTransform in g2d. But that is just my guess, I need someone who is very certain on how to use it to give an explanation and confirmation.

Comment: I "think" this compounds the supplied transform with the graphics current transform, which would allow you to apply a scale, do some work, then apply rotation, although I'm fairly certain setTransform does the same thing...:P

Comment: Okay, after having a closer look at the docs, transform seems to merge the transforms, setTransform seems to override it

Comment: @MadProgrammer Good to see you around. Marco13 has confirmed our speculations. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<sub>There is a very broad range of possible answers, ranging from "It does what the JavaDoc says" to fully quoting several chapters of [the graphics programming bible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_Graphics:_Principles_and_Practice). I'll try to give an in-between answer. It's closer to the first option, yet some links lead to information that may be a bit more detailed than necessary to grasp the basic concepts.</sub>

The transform of a [`Graphics2D`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html) is an [`AffineTransform`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html) that describes how objects should be transformed before they are drawn. Such an `AffineTransform` is a [Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_%28mathematics%29) that can be imagined as something that modifies the positions of all points of the drawn objects. For example, it can be a [rotation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) so that the objects are rotated before they are drawn.

An example: When you are in the `paintComponent` method of some `JPanel`, and have obtained the `Graphics2D`, then you may perform drawing operations:

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics gr) {
    super.paintComponent(gr);
    Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D)gr;
    ...

    // Draw a rectangle
    g.drawRect(0,0,50,100);
}
```

The rectangle that is drawn there will be 50 pixels wide and 100 pixels high.

Now, you can apply a new transformation to the `Graphics2D` object before drawing:

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics gr) {
    super.paintComponent(gr);
    Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D)gr;
    ...

    // Obtain an AffineTransform that describes a scaling
    AffineTransform scalingTransform =      
        AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(2,2);

    // Apply the transform to the graphics
    g.transform(scalingTransform );

    // Draw a rectangle. 
    g.drawRect(0,0,50,100);
}
```

The rectangle that is drawn there now will be 100 pixels wide and 200 pixels high, due to the transform that scales everything by a factor of 2. You could also have used a transform that performs a rotation, with something like

```
g.transform(AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(Math.toDegrees(45)));
```

so that the rectangle would be rotated by 45 degrees.

This is basically what the `transform` method does, regarding the API and its effect.

A side note: It is true that the `rotate(...)`, `translate(...)`, `shear(...)` and `scale(...)` methods of the `Graphics2D` are just convenience methods. Instead of

```
g.transform(AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(Math.toDegrees(45)));
```

you can simply call

```
g.rotate(Math.toDegrees(45));
```

to achieve the same effect. The `transform` method is very generic, as it may receive arbitrary transformation matrices that may have been composed elsewhere - e.g. in some other method, where the `Graphics2D` object is simply not available.

---

If you wonder what the method does **internally**: That's actually quite simple. It just performs a [Matrix Multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication). It multiplies the `AffineTransform` that is contained in the `Graphics2D` with the `AffineTransform` that is passed to the `transform` method.

The multiplication of such transformation matrices can be imagined as applying the respective transformations, in reverse order:

```
AffineTransform scalingByFactor2 = 
    AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(2,2);

AffineTransform rotationBy45degrees = 
    AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(Math.toDegrees(45));

g.transform(rotationBy45degrees);
g.transform(scalingByFactor2);
g.drawRect(0,0,50,100);
```

As a result, a rectangle will be drawn, that is

1. **First** scaled by a factor of 2 in x- and y direction
2. **then** rotated by 45 degrees

So the result will be a larger, rotated rectangle.

If you had applied the operations like this

```
g.transform(scalingByFactor2);
g.transform(rotationBy45degrees);
```

then the rectangle would appear like a large, diamond-like-shaped object.

> Edit in response to the comments:

The reason why the objects appear to be different is that the transformations are applied independently. That is, they are applied to the objects that may already have been transformed by other transforms. I think the example of a rectangle (or square) may be rather intuitive here:

[image: TransformationOrder]

This is basically the same as in usual painting or drawing programs, where you apply one transformation to an object, and then another one, and the order of the transformations affects the result.

---

There have been some guesses about the difference between the `transform` and the `setTransform` method. And as MadProgrammer finally pointed out:

The `transform` method concatenates the current transform of the graphics object with the new one (that is: It multiplies the matrices). You can use it to "compose" several transformations, as shown with the rotation and scaling examples above.

In contrast to that, the [`Graphics2D#setTransform`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#setTransform-java.awt.geom.AffineTransform-) method serves an entirely different purpose, and the documentation contains the corresponding warning:

> WARNING: This method should **never** be used to apply a new coordinate transform on top of an existing transform

It should only be used to restore the original transform of the graphics, after a sequence to `transform` calls, as shown in the example of the JavaDoc.

Comment: Well explained. I will accept your answer. Thank you for the detailed explanation :)

Comment: Can you explain why different order of transformation (i.e. rotate then scale vs scale then rotate) generate different results? Really hope you can answer this :)

Comment: @user3437460 I added a section explaining this in more detail

Comment: Your explanation is simple and effective. I get it now. But how come if I do a translation *followed by* a shear (e.g: `g2d.shear(2,0)` then `g2d.translate(100,150)`), while shearing it shift the position of the image as well? Sorry for being "greedy" in asking questions. I have already upvoted your solution :p

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Some operations refer to the origin, which may have counter-intuitive effects. E.g. when you rotate an object, it will not necessarily rotate about its center. And similarly, when you translate an object, the shear will also affect its position, because the translated object is sheared. This can usually be avoided by 1. Moving the center of the object to the origin, 2. Doing the shear (or rotation), 3. Moving the object back to its original position. Also see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html#rotate-double-double-double-

Answer (score 0):

You use this method to modify how a Graphics2D object will appear before it's rendered into a device space, such as a screen or a piece of paper. For example, you can use it to do things like scale, rotate, and shear an image in response to the user pressing the Scale/Rotate/Shear buttons in your application.

A Graphics2D object is born with a field for keeping track of the transform, which represents an approximation of the 'device space' (e.g., 1920 x 1080) into which the object will be rendered. This transformation is calculated and applied *at runtime* to the object so that it renders properly in the available screen real-estate (or printer page, or projector display, etc.)

By applying the `transform(AffineTransform Tx)` method, you're telling the system that you want to change how the Graphics2D object will look when it's finally rendered; e.g., scaling or rotating the object. What the documentation is saying is that your new transform will be applied to the Graphics2D object *before* its original transform is applied to fit it into the display attached to the device in which the JVM is running; all of that happens prior to rendering.

Comment: So in what specific scenarios do we use `transform()` and how does `transform()` affect the current AffineTransform object (g2d's field)?

Comment: There is no Graphics2D.transform() method. If you mean the method you originally inquired about, you'd use it (for example) to scale an image in response to a user clicking the "Zoom In" button, or to scale it up or down automatically to prepare it for printing.

Comment: Sorry - I clarified my answer to address the actual questions you originally asked.

Comment: Maybe you could give some simple coding examples on using transform to perform things like rotate and translate? Further more, in what case would we want to use transform when we could actually do things like rotation/translation/shearing without it?

Comment: I don't have any code samples handy (they're at home), and it's been long(!) time since I used this library. However, the related methods in Graphics2D such as translate(double, double) and rotate(double) may ultimately delegate to the transform(AffineTransform) method. If that's the case, you might have a situation where subclassing Graphics2D and overriding the transform(AffineTransform) method would be advantageous. You might also want to do something specialized by applying an AffineTransform implementation that's not possible w/ other methods, such as simultaneously scaling and rotating.